# How can I query an SQL record and include column data form an additional row?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have some data in a **SQL** table that looks like the below:

```
TIMESTAMP    SYMBOL  PRICE  VOLUME  RATIO  ITERATION
2017-10-04   ABC     1.23   12      0.78   1
2017-10-05   ABC     1.33   10      0.49   2
2017-10-06   ABC     1.73   10      0.69   3
2017-10-04   XYZ     1.73   10      0.69   1
...
```

I am trying to write a query that will return all the records matching a `timestamp` and `symbol` (using a simple `WHERE` clause), but **also** include the previous `price` from the current records previous `iteration`.

For example, if I want to return all the records matching `symbol=ABC` and `timestamp=2017-10-06`, the query would return:

```
TIMESTAMP    SYMBOL  PRICE  VOLUME  RATIO  ITERATION  PREV_PRICE
2017-10-06   ABC     1.73   10      0.69   3          1.33
```

where `PREV_PRICE` is `price` of the record matching `symbol=ABC` and also `iteration=2` (current records iteration value minus 1).

I can do this via code by implementing several queries and loops, but I am hoping to find a way to do this in **SQL** itself.

It is possible to retrieve the `price` data from the record of a previous iteration of matching the same `symbol` as the queried record?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most databases support the ANSI standard `lag()`.  But you have to be careful, because you need to do the `lag()` before filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(t.price) over (partition by symbol order by timestamp) as prev_price
      from t
      where t.symbol = 'ABC'
     ) t
where t.timestamp = '2017-10-06';
```

Filtering on `symbol` in the subquery is safe, because that is used for partitioning.  However, the filter on `timestamp` needs to be in the outer query so the `lag()` does its job.

Comment: Amazing. I had not heard of `lag()`. Its super useful. And for others reading this, I am using MS SQL (on Azure). And it supports `lag()` no problem.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is join the table to itself using the criteria you outlined in your question. This should work:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.PRICE as PREV_PRICE
FROM my_table t1
    LEFT JOIN my_table t2 ON (t2.SYMBOL = t1.SYMBOL AND t2.ITERATION = (t1.ITERATION - 1))
WHERE t1.TIMESTAMP = '2017-10-06'
    AND t1.SYMBOL = 'ABC'
```

You can also do same with a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*,
    (SELECT PRICE FROM my_table t2 WHERE t2.ITERATION = (t1.ITERATION - 1)) AS PREV_PRICE
FROM my_table t1
WHERE t1.TIMESTAMP = '2017-10-06'
    AND t1.SYMBOL = 'ABC'
```

Answer (score 0):

Include a subquery to get the previous price. Get the maximum price for the timestamp that is less than the given timestamp. This will give the price corresponding to the previous timestamp.

```
SELECT y1.*, 
      (SELECT max (price)
         FROM yourtable y
        WHERE symbol = 'ABC'
          AND timestamp < '2017-10-06') prev_price
  FROM yourtable y1
 WHERE symbol = 'ABC'
   AND timestamp = '2017-10-06'
```